# What is the best practice to store jwt token in client side?

Tags: security, jwt, httpsession

Is it safe to store jwt token in HttpSession? If it is not what is the best practice to store jwt token. So that it can be used for further usages in client.

```
public void setLoggedinUserInSession(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String jwtToken){
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("token", jwtToken);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to put the clients JWT token in to the servers HTTP Session? There should be no reason to do it this way. Sure, you can put the JWT token into a cookie (note: not into the session cookie, just pass the token value over a cookie header). But why do you want to store it in the servers memory? It makes the solution less secure to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question - how to store JWT tokens on the client. Cookies are one of the ways to go. There are many small and big things to take care of, but they all are summarized by OWASP ASVS: https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/v4.0.3/4.0/en/0x12-V3-Session-management.md

One important thing: HTTP Session is not the way to go. Have a look how to handle cookies https://www.baeldung.com/java-servlet-cookies-session#1-create-a-cookie and do this instead.